# qr code malware

Tags: mobile, qr-code, malware

I read several articles about this (e.g., [How QR Codes can Deliver Malware](http://www.infosecisland.com/blogview/20814-How-QR-Codes-Can-Deliver-Malware.html)), and it seems to create quite so buzz.

From what I read, all the so-called "malware" are links to malicious web sties or apps. My question is: are there other forms of QR code malware? If not, then what's new about this type of malware?

Comment: The title of the article is misleading. I would word it "*How QR Codes Can Let Users Visit Webpages and Get Scammed Due to Their Own Gullibility*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QR codes have a maximum payload of ~4K so there's no chance of buffer overflows or anything like that to the QR scanner.

However, they can be used to direct people to malicious content in a couple of interesting ways.

1. You know that the computer visiting a link is likely to be a mobile device. If you have a browser exploit for, say, iPhone - you can deliver it once the user visits the web page.
2. Using a very long URL, you could fool the user into thinking they are visiting a "safe" site.  If a QR scanner only shows the first, say, 20 characters of a URL, you could craft a QR which goes to

   ```
   https://www.VerySafeSite.com.evilsite.com
   ```
3. While the scanner may not be susceptible to buffer overflows, the addressbook may be. So crafting a vCard with an abnormally long field may provide a vector for attack - although this is highly unlikely.
4. Sticker attacks are possible. A criminal could find a poster with a legitimate QR code and place a sticker of a QR code over it. That would likely trick people into scanning.

So, essentially, it's virtually impossible to have a malicious QR code - only a malicious destination.

Comment: For vCard, wouldn't users become suspicious when they see extremely long fields? Is it possible to have hidden/invisible fields to exploit vulnerabilities in the addressbook apps? The "sticker attack" example is interesting. Are there cases of such attacks reported?

Comment: I've documented a sticker attack on my blog http://shkspr.mobi/blog/index.php/2011/12/how-to-prevent-qr-hijacking/

Comment: Actually, it was possible to create bufferOverflow with them: look at [CVE-2018-3900](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-3900)

Answer (score 0):

QR codes themselves are not executable and do not contain executable data, so just reading one should be safe. As @Blender said, they certainly can link to malware, but are not malicious themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibilty to exploit apps and their users when qr codes are used in points of sales terminals but that would require indepth knowledge of the app. If they only contain a URL then its the same as opening the same url any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, all of the QR code malware that I've seen have just been links to malicious websites or apps.

QR codes can contain data other than just links, such as straight text, contact information (VCARD) or event information (VCALENDAR).  It can even contain raw data, which in theory could contain executable code, but most QR code reader software will probably ignore this sort of code because it has no idea how to handle the embedded data.